# How can I install nemo- plugins for 22.04

Tags: filemanager, plugins, nemo

Nemo File manager is part of the default Ubuntu repository. The only extension is the current repository is "nemo-fileroller".

The PPA's I used for past releases are not maintained any more and do not cover 22.04.

How can I install any of those?

- nemo-terminal
- rabbitvcs-
- nemo-seahorse
- nemo-share
- nemo-compare

Comment: I managed to install all, so the good news is it can be done and it runs in 22.04 (using XFCE). The bad news is you have to hunt down all sources from the net individually and install them manually. That a trial an error process involving copying and changing file permissions.

Comment: Can you please let us know how to install these from source? I need to install all of them (https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo-extensions) , I will use as required.

Comment: Sorry, I would have posted an answer it I could remember more. Best guess is to check out the "Readme" and "Install" infos with the sources. It probably requires a bit of experience in working on the Linux command line.